# ubuntu 13.04 doesn't recognize second 40gb hard drive

Tags: hardware

I have 2 hdd
320 gb + 40 gb
the 320 gb has windows 7
i am trying to install ubuntu 13.04 on the 40 gb but ubuntu 13.04 doesn't recognize it when installing
but ubuntu 13.04 recognize it when i choose try ubuntu 
i removed the 320 giga and use only the 40 giga and ubuntu did not recognize it 
after partitioning the 40 giga with Gparted 2partitions the first partition is about 33 giga  ext4 the second partition about 5 giga swap

still have the same problem
when installing ubuntu it can not recognize the 40 giga hd

Image when installing:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/02PMyyV.png]

Image when try ubuntu:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/yMjdCdt.png]

Answer (score 0):

If it's SATA, SCSI, or SAS try unplugging the drive while the system is on and plugging them back in (while the system is still on).

Comment: it's SATA and it is not hot swap

Comment: All SATA drives and boards are hot swappable, if they are actually conformant to the SATA standard.